# Minmuim steps to reach a point an array

Tags: algorithm

There is an infinite one dimensional array ranging from (-infinity, infinity). You are currently at cell number 0. Your goal is to reach cell number H. There are two kinds of moves allowed.
 U =steps to the right (positive side).
 D =steps to the left (negative side).
We have to find the minimum no. of moves if(possiable)

For h=2 u=2 d=1
first move 2 steps to the right to reach cell number 2. Then 1 step to the left to reach cell number 1 and finally 2 more steps to the right to reach the goal. Thus 3 moves are required which is the minimum.

What are the algorithms to solve this question.My approach make a recursive call i.e h+u and h-d , untill h==0.

Comment: @EdHeal You didnt understand the problem. He can only move in a given direction by U steps (increasing) or D steps (decreasing). Binary search is thus not what OP is looking for. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation : this is more what you're looking for ... :)

Comment: @pramodmaurya it's not a array in the common programming perspective. Actually the purpose is, starting from 0, to navigate through ℤ with the given constraints (U and D) until you reach the target H.

Comment: @user4213270 - As to your example. According to my understanding you finally reached cell 3 (+2 -1 +2) but the h=2. Shouldn't it be h=3?

Answer (score 2):

Let's *m* be a number of moves that has to be made toward the positive side and *n* a number of moves that has to be made toward the negative side. *m* and *n* must satisfy the following equation:

```
h = u * m - d * n
```

We know *h*, *u* and *d*. The equation for your example will look as follows (I assume that *h* should be 3 and not 2, see also my comment):

```
3 = m * 2 - n * 1
->
n = 2 * m  - 3
```

We also know that *m* >= 0, *n* >= 0 and *m* and *n* are integers. Now the easy way to find *m* and *n* will be to calculate *n* for *m* = 0,1,2,3,4... until you will receive *n* that satisfy all the conditions (you can also calculate *m* based on *n*). In your example it will be:

```
m = 0 -> n = -3 is an integer but n < 0 so it is not an answer
m = 1 -> n = -1 is an integer but n < 0 so it is not an answer
m = 2 -> n = 1
```

So the answer is *m*=2 and *n*=1. You don't have to check results for other *m* because you will always receive higher values (*h = u*m - d*n* is an increasing funcion).

It is not everything. There may exist equations which do not have integer solutions. In this partocular case we are considering the linear diophantine equations which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) have integer solutions:

**if and only if *h* is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of *d* and *u***

Let's return to your example again. GCD of 2 and 1 is 1 and 3 is a multiplication of 1 so an integer solution exists. However, let's consider *h*=9, *d*=2 and *u*=4. GCD(2,4) is 2 and 9 is not a multiplication 2 so there is no solution. You have to check this condition before trying to find *m* and *n* because otherwise you will end in the infinitive loop.